# How to set a Placeholder in Select/Option with NgModel in Angular2 (7)?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to set a default value/placheholder in my select option, it looks easy to do but I wasn't able to do it. I've tried different things but I got the same result.

```
<select class="form-control border custom-select" [compareWith]="compareFn"
        [(ngModel)]="skill.category">
    <option selected disabled="disabled">Chose a category...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [ngValue]="cat"
            [hidden]="cat.id === 1">{{cat.name}}</option>
</select>

compareFn(c1: Skill, c2: Skill): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```

My output is something like this:

- [CATEGORY id=1] default //I want this to be totaly hidden (id=1 hidden)
- dropdown {
- [Chose a category...]
- [CATEGORY id=2]
- [CATEGORY id=3]
- [CATEGORY id=4]
- ...
  } end dropdown

Comment: So you would want category id 1 to be the default selected item but you don't want it selectable by the user?

Comment: Can you please state (1) what you want and (2) what the code is doing or not doing that is different from what you want?

Comment: no, I have 5 categories from DB.
Category with id 1 must not be in the dropdown and I want the selected value to be a MSG setted by me "Choose a category..."

Comment: @theMayer [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqkycb)
this is just an output

Comment: please share component as well with categories , as selected to default option would set "choose category" - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6pmfod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use slice pipe

1. slice: 1 - if the value to be removed is always first option

```html
<select class="form-control border custom-select">
    <option selected disabled="disabled">Chose a category...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let cat of categories| slice:1" [ngValue]="cat">
      {{cat.name}}</option>
</select>
```

code reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay8zzk

Please refer this link for more details on Slice Pipe - https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Answer (score 1):

in template you can in many ways, one more is:

```
<select class="form-control border custom-select" [compareWith]="compareFn"
        [(ngModel)]="skill.category">
    <mat-label>Chose a category...</mat-label>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of categories" >
       <option *ngIf="cat.id !== 1" [ngValue]="cat">{{cat.name}}</option>
    </ng-container>
</select>
```

use mat-label if the value od the disabled option is not a valid option,
the user must not be able to select a not valid option
do you really need the value of the selected to be the entire object?
or better removing before template

```
http.get<cat[]>('url').pipe(
   map(list => list.filter(one => one.id !== 1))
).subs...
```

or even better removing from query in the database

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not sending down the result for ID: 1 as you will not be utilizing it. Component would be something like:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  category = 0;
  categories = [
    { id: 2, name: "Opel" },
    { id: 3, name: "Mazda" },
    { id: 4, name: "BMW" }
  ];
}
```

Template:

```
<select class="form-control border custom-select" [(ngModel)]="category">
    <option selected disabled="disabled" [value]="0">Chose a category...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [value]="cat.id">{{cat.name}}</option>
</select>
```